# Mocking an entire class in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

It seems so easy, but I can't get the following to work. I was looking for answers in the following posts, but although related, do not cover this exact case.

- [Mocking an entire class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660332/mocking-an-entire-class)
- [Mocking a class: Mock() or patch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180769/mocking-a-class-mock-or-patch)
- [Mock entire python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004540/mock-entire-python-class) (where actually only a method is mocked)

I have the following class under test:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.api_service = APIService(x, y)
    def my_method():
        pass
```

In the test case, I want to test `my_method`, and want to mock `APIService`, which is not used at all anyway in `my_method`. What should I mock/patch?

Things that did not work:

```
@patch('path.to.APIService')
class APITestCase(TestCase):
    def test_that_my_method_works(self, _):
        a = A(1, 2)
        a.my_method
        # Still calls real APIService

@patch.object(APIService, '__init__', return_value=Mock())
class APITestCase(TestCase):
    def test_that_my_method_works(self, _):
        a = A(1, 2)
        a.my_method
        # TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'Mock'


@patch.object(APIService, '__init__', return_value=None)
class APITestCase(TestCase):
    def test_that_my_method_works(self, _):
        a = A(1, 2)
        a.my_method
        # Still calls real APIService
```

Comment: You need to mock the `APIService` class with respect to *where you are testing*. So your first example should actually be something like `path.to.A.APIService`. You want to mock the APIService that is being used where you are testing class A.

Comment: Read the [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) doc.

Comment: Thanks! I did read that section, but didn't understand it (nor realize that it was relevant) until you pointed this out to me.